# Getting the error message `error.toJSON() is not a function` while handling errors in axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, axios

When I run my code, i get the message `error.toJSON is not a function`. How am I supposed to handle this error better?

```
const installDependencies = async (BASE_URL, body) => {
  try {
    const headers = {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
    };
    const response = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/data`, body, { headers });
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.response?.data, error.toJSON());
    throw new Error("Failed to install dependencies");
  }
};
```

Comment: `toJSON()` is not a standard JavaScript method. Maybe you mean `JSON.stringify(error)`?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible for your `catch` to handle either an `AxiosError` or any other throwable.

Axios provides a utility function to determine if it's the former

```js
const installDependencies = async (baseURL, body) => {
  try {
    return await axios.post("/data", body, { baseURL });
  } catch (error) {
    if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
      console.error(error.response?.data, error.toJSON());
    } else {
      console.error(error);
    }

    throw new Error("Failed to install dependencies");
  }
};
```

See https://github.com/axios/axios/#typescript

---

FYI your headers were redundant and Axios provides a simpler option for setting a `baseURL`.